# bootstrap popover content setting

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

bootstrap popover currrently expects this:

```
<a href="#" id="example" class="btn btn-danger"  rel="popover" data-content="It's so simple to create a tooltop for my website!" data-original-title="Twitter Bootstrap Popover">hover for popover</a>  

$("#example").popover({placement:'bottom'});
```

..expects you to define data-content in template or dynamically pass it in jquery.

Is there anyway it can support format like below:

..the point being able to define content/title in blocks

```
<div id="example">
<div class="original-title">
Twitter Bootstrap Popover
</div>
<div class="data-content">
It's so simple to create a tooltop for my website!
</div>
<a>hover for popover</a>
<div>

$("#example").popover({placement:'bottom'})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, no, since the popover script is basically extending the functionally of the tooltip script, but nothing is impossible. You can modify the script and add custom `data-attributes` to support your markup yourself, but then when updates come around you will have to do it again if you want to support your edits, or not update at all.

Answer (score 1):

I think that can be possible using a javascript code to give the content of this divs to the elements but is not recommended.

```
$("a").attr("data-title",$(".data-title").html()).attr(".data-content",$(".data-content").html());
$('a').popover({placement:'bottom'})
```